# Apache poi with intellij idea Error CTFramePr not found

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, apache-poi

I use Apache POI(version 3.17) in my maven project with the following dependencies, artifactIds: poi, poi-ooxml to manipulate docx files.

3 days ago the project build fine and unit tests are run correctly. But today I got this message and I can't solve:

> Error:java: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for
>   org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTFramePr not
>   found

A can't use this class: org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTFramePr

Please help to solve this problem.

Thanks in advice.
R.

Comment: Did you try [reading the Apache POI FAQ entry on the topic](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10025), then [following the instructions given](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10025)? If not,  what happens when you do?

Comment: You are right  it should another dependency: ooxml-schemas latest version (currently 1.3). Now it's working for me. Thank you.